# How to rephrase MySQL query with when `IN` seems not allowed?

Tags: mysql

This MySQL-Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t_1
WHERE t_1.title_search IN
(
  SELECT title_search FROM t_2 limit 1, 10
);
```

produces this error:

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

After some googling I found mysqlf on [this Developer Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-errors.html) of MySQL. I understand, that this form of query is not supported. Is there a way to rephrase this?

Comment: do you have some kind of id in t_2?

Comment: What's the actual purpose of the query? You want to select 10 completely random rows from `title_search` and get the associated table_1 rows? Dumbed down questions get dumb answers.

Comment: @Dalen, yes it is a primary column called `t_2.id`.

Comment: @Dan: I want to select the value of the column `title_search` from 10 (arbitrary) rows in the table `t_2` and join them with the column `title_search` in the table `t_1`. the purpose is just to verify, that there are *links*. I want to specify the behavior later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t_1.* 
FROM table_1 t_1, table_2 t_2
WHERE t_1.title_search = t_2.title_search
limit 1,10;
```

If you're using the limit for, say a web paging, then the limit is best the last clause, if however you are using limit to restrict the results from the IN clause (you actually only want to match on the first 10 records of the T_2 table), then the above is not correct.

Comment: You are almost there, please specify where the second `title_search` comes from and I'll upvote you

Comment: we are not sure about table_2 existing, from your first question you did not name the table, but you used the alias "t_2".  I added the table in, and used the alias that I thought you meant to use.

Comment: Heads up, I'm not the "asker" (also known as OP in SO=tackOverflow). I'm just a by stander voter.